# ASP.NET MVC URLs - Correct approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

Currently my project has a page `domain/cocktail` which displays a list of all cocktails. If user wants to filter the list he can choose sorting order, cocktail's starting letter and strength. So url will look like `domain/cocktail?letter=B&sort=nu&strength=2&page=4`.

As I've read it is not the best choice to use such urls. What approach can you suggest to get SEO-friendly URLs with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC applications use the ASP.NET routing system, which decides how URLs map to particular controllers and actions.

Under default routing system when a browser requests http://yoursite/Home, it gets back the output from Controller's `action` method. Therefore if you use `CoctailList` action method to derive the list from backend, user will need to point at http://yoursite/Controller/CoctailList

Comment: Now I have CocktailController with Index action. So it is better not to use Index action for such purposes? And what shall I do with parameters? If I have only page parameter it will look like domain/cocktail/3. But with several parameters it looks like in my post above.

Comment: See when a browser requests http://yoursite/Home, it gets back the output from HomeController’s Index method. Therefore if the browser request http://yoursite/ConctailController , it will get the index() method from ConctailController. And http://yoursite/ConctailController/CockListFunc will point to CockListFunc in your controller. Therefore write a CockListFunc which returns a View listing all the coctails. You need to bind your model to the controller and represent it in view

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I would POST the search criteria, but I would put the page on end of the URL like:

```
domain/cocktail/2
domain/cocktail/3
```

You can post the data by creating a JSON object:

```
var viewModel = new Object();
viewModel.Letter = "B";
viewModel.Sort = "nu";
$.post("/domain/cocktail/" + page, viewModel, function () { });
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `public ActionResult Index(int page, Options opt)` where `Options` is a class with properties `Sort`, `Strength`, etc. If I try to use this action, I get error "`/cocktail/1` not found" for `/domain/cocktail/1` url. If I pass page as a property of Options class I get OK response, but nothing happens (maybe action must return something different from View)?